Whether functions in 2D Sobolev Space $W^{1,2}$ space are countinuous(a.e.)?
Q1:Whether functions in 2D $W^{1,2}$ space are continuous(a.e.)?
I've learned that functions in 1D $W^{1,p}$ are a.e. absolute continuous.(Evans PDE chapter5 problem4)
I also know that functions like $u(x)=|x|^{-\alpha}$, $u \in W^{1,p}(U)$ iff $\alpha<\frac{n-p}{p}$. So if n=3 then $u$ is not continuous.
So what happens when it's 2-Dimensional space?
(I've heard that when n=kp it could be a hard situation to prove theories, but I'm just trying to check for counter-examples to convince me: well, something not continuous are indeed contained in this circumstance).
More to ask:
In Frederic Helein's book of 'Harmonic Maps...',Chapter3: Wente' inequality.
In 2D-situation, if
$-\bigtriangleup\phi=\{a,b\} $ in $\Omega$, $\phi=0$ on $\partial\Omega$,
where $\{a,b\}:={\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial b}{\partial y}}-{\frac{\partial a}{\partial y}}{\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}}\,.$ a,b  $\in H^1(\Omega,R)$
then $\phi$ is continuous.
Q2:So it might be $u(x)\in W^{1,2},f\in L^1$,$\bigtriangleup u=f$ but $u$ is not continuous?
How can this kind of examples be constructed?

After some aimless serach, I think i find the answer in the following question:
Are all functions in the Sobolev space $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ continuous and bounded?
$$
    u(x) = \begin{cases} \log \log (1+\frac{1}{|x|}),
        \quad & |x|<\frac{1}{e-1} \\ 0,\quad &|x|\ge \frac{1}{e-1}\end{cases} $$
